# iOS create touch event programmatically

Tags: ios

My goal is to make gesture event programmatically.

For example, There is a uiwebview,

In my code:

myWebview.gestureLeft(5); 
then Webview scroll to left for 5 pixels like when I touch to left for 5 pixels even I didnt touch on webview.

Is it possible?

Now...I am going to implement when I shake phone, webview's content will shake.

But I dont need use call javascript functions.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Now this is a typical XY problem. You don't want programmatic touch events - you simply want to scroll the contents of the web view's backing `UIScrollView` back and forth. Check out the documentation of that class for further info.

Comment: Hey, Thanks...but..it is not easy such that...In that webpage, While swiping, Special thing happens.. My Say is that webpage is a little special, it is not a problem about Scroll