# Implement UITouches Gesture programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Implement UITouches Gesture grammatically:

I want to implement touches gesture by xcode itself,
I looked [iOS create touch event programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825663/ios-create-touch-event-programmatically)
but there is no answer.

If I am searching any wrong thing please let me know.

Comment: what exactly you mean by implement touch gesture by XCode itself, can you post some scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to synthesize a touch event on the iPhone: you have to use undisclosed API, so you have a high probability of breaking on every update of the iOS and getting rejecting from Apple.

Here's a [link](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html) that demonstrates how to synthesize a touch event on the iPhone:

Here's another question on StackOverflow: [How to send a touch event to iPhone OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746452/how-to-send-a-touch-event-to-iphone-os)